# Advantages and drawbacks of different ways using Either-types

Tags: object-oriented, either

I am writing software for compiling programs. Therefore have a `Compiler` that compiles a given sourcecode. It then returns a `CompileResult` that is similiar to an `Either` type (it is actually internally delegating to an `Either` object). Now there can be 2 (non-exceptional) cases:

1. The compile is successfull (`CompileSuccess`)
2. The compile failed (`CompileFailure`)

Let's assume the compile was successfull. I have seen two or maybe three ways to handle it:

1. `return new CompileResult( new CompileSuccess("success info") )` where `CompileResult` contains a `CompileSuccess`.
2. `return new CompileSuccess("success info")` where `CompileSuccess` implements `CompileResult`.
3. `CompileResult.from( CompileSuccess("success info") )` which could possibly implemented to return either a `CompileResult` object or a `CompileSuccess` object (as in 2.)

Are there other ways to accomplish what I want to do? I saw the 2. "inheritation" way in Google guavas Either and in Scalas Either. In guava the 3. way is used for the `Option` type. What are the differences and when to choose what?

Comment: There's not much of a difference between this question and asking what are the ways one can construct any other kind of object. To me the bigger question is what's your motivation for writing your own Either if you already have an Either available?

Comment: For example I can use different methods that are more clear to someone that uses my classes. `CompileResult.compileSuccessful()` is more natural than `CompileResult.isRight()`.

Comment: You could get that approach by subclassing. In my opinion the interesting bits aren't how the Either is created, but how it's used. For example, `if (either.isRight()) { foo(either.getRight()); }` is a sucky interface since you can still screw up, but the alternative is to use lambdas or visitors, so if you're stuck in Java 7 you have to choose between something slightly error-prone or something foolproof but incredibly verbose. As for your actual question, Guava makes a lot of use of static factories for Java 6 type inference.

Comment: Yeah, I currently don't subclass it but implement it and delegate to an internal `Either` instance. Means I'm not duplicating any code in the `Either` class. I am using groovy 2.3 and reimplemented `Either` and `Option`similiar to guava. But I see now why they use static factories. It still bothers me if a `CompileSuccess` *is a* `CompileResult` or if a `CompileResult` (may) *have a* `CompileSuccess`

Comment: Composition is the only thing that makes sense to me there.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): **[My value checker function needs to return both a boolean and a message](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/274096)**

Comment: @Snowman How is this related/duplicate?!

Comment: @valenterry the other question is about returning complex objects with very similar semantic meaning to the objects described in this question.

Answer (score -1):

The major issue with your two first solutions is that you couple the compile phase and the creation/instancing of the result. Your third way add a dependency of your class with an unique way to create the result (CompileResult).
Let's solve the first point (delegating Result creation):

```
class SuccessDetails {
    private String description;
    public SuccessDetails (String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
class FailureDetails {
    private String description;
    public FailureDetails (String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
class FailResultDetailed extends Result {
    private FailureDetails details;
    public FailResultDetailed (FailureDetails details) { this.details = details; }
}
class SuccessResultDetailed extends Result {
    private SuccessDetails details;
    public SuccessResultDetailed (SuccessDetails details) { this.details = details; }
}
class Result {}
class SuccessResult extends Result {
    private String description;
    public SuccessResult (String description) { this.description = description; }
}
class FailResult extends Result {
    private String description;
    public FailResult (String description) { this.description = description; }
}
interface IResultFactory {
    public SuccessResultDetailed success (SuccessDetails details);
    public FailResultDetailed fail (FailureDetails details);
}
class ResultFactory implements IResultFactory {
    public ResultFactory () { }
    public SuccessResultDetailed success (SuccessDetails details) { return new SuccessResultDetailed(details); }
    public FailResultDetailed fail (FailureDetails details) { return new FailResultDetailed(details); }
}
class Compiler {
    private IResultFactory resultFactory;
    public Compiler (IResultFactory resultFactory) { this.resultFactory = resultFactory; }
    public Result compile (String code, Boolean result) {
        if (result)
            return resultFactory.success(new SuccessDetails("Ok"));
        else
            return resultFactory.fail(new FailureDetails("You've made a mistake"));
    }
}
```

Now your are free to change the way you handle and create the Result object, but you might want to add some details.
The most intuitive way to solve it (for a OO developer) is to extract the details in a bunch of other classes:

```
class SuccessWithWarningsDetails extends SuccessDetails {
    private int[] lines;
    public SuccessWithWarningsDetails (String description, int[] lines) {
        super(description);
        this.lines = lines;
    }
}
class CompilerThatThrowsWarnings {
    private IResultFactory resultFactory;
    public CompilerThatThrowsWarnings (IResultFactory resultFactory) { this.resultFactory = resultFactory; }
    public Result compile (String code, Boolean result) {
        if (result)
            return resultFactory.success(new SuccessWithWarningsDetails("Ok", new int[] {1, 2, 3}));
        else
            return resultFactory.fail(new FailureDetails("You've made a mistake"));
    }
}
```

But again, we couple the compile phase and the creation/instancing of the result.
We can try to apply the same process we have done the first time:

```
interface IResultDetailsFactory {
    public SuccessDetails success (String description);
    public SuccessWithWarningsDetails successWithWarnings (String description, int[] lines);
    public FailureDetails failure (String description);
}
class ResultDetailsFactory implements IResultDetailsFactory{
    public ResultDetailsFactory () { }
    public SuccessDetails success (String description) { return new SuccessDetails(description); }
    public SuccessWithWarningsDetails successWithWarnings (String description, int[] lines) { return new SuccessWithWarningsDetails(description, lines); }
    public FailureDetails failure (String description) { return new FailureDetails(description); }
}
class CompilerThatThrowsWarningsWithoutCreation {
    private IResultFactory resultFactory;
    private IResultDetailsFactory resultDetailsFactory;
    public CompilerThatThrowsWarningsWithoutCreation (IResultFactory resultFactory, IResultDetailsFactory resultDetailsFactory) {
        this.resultFactory = resultFactory;
        this.resultDetailsFactory = resultDetailsFactory;
    }
    public Result compile (String code, Boolean result) {
        if (result)
            return resultFactory.success(resultDetailsFactory.successWithWarnings("Ok", new int[] {1, 2, 3}));
        else
            return resultFactory.fail(resultDetailsFactory.failure("You've made a mistake"));
    }
}
```

We are so close to the ending, if only we hadn't the resultFactory depency...
Why? because we only care about producing Result, not how they are arranged.

```
interface IResultDetailsAndResultFactory {
    public SuccessResultDetailed success (String description);
    public SuccessResultDetailed successWithWarnings (String description, int[] lines);
    public FailResultDetailed failure (String description);
}
class ResultDetailsAndResultFactory implements IResultDetailsAndResultFactory {
    private IResultFactory resultFactory;
    public ResultDetailsAndResultFactory (IResultFactory resultFactory) { this.resultFactory = resultFactory; }
    public SuccessResultDetailed success (String description) { return resultFactory.success(new SuccessDetails(description)); }
    public SuccessResultDetailed successWithWarnings (String description, int[] lines) { return resultFactory.success(new SuccessWithWarningsDetails(description, lines)); }
    public FailResultDetailed failure (String description) { return resultFactory.fail(new FailureDetails(description)); }
}
class CompilerThatThrowsWarningsWithoutCreationAndResult {
    private IResultDetailsAndResultFactory resultFactory;
    public CompilerThatThrowsWarningsWithoutCreationAndResult  (IResultDetailsAndResultFactory resultFactory) {
        this.resultFactory = resultFactory;
    }
    public Result compile (String code, Boolean result) {
        if (result)
            return resultFactory.successWithWarnings("Ok", new int[] {1, 2, 3});
        else
            return resultFactory.failure("You've made a mistake");
    }
}
```

Now we have not only a Compile phase that only depends on a factory to build detailed Results, but we also have results that only depends on a factory to handle the way they will be processed.

Comment: And what is the point of having all those factories? As I see it, there is no likely need for the compiler to ever return anything else than the failure/success objects it knows how to build itself. After all, it is the compiler that defines what data may be inside these objects, and it's neither the job of the compiler nor of the returned object to interpret that data. Thus, I would see the OP's way #2 (inheritance approach) as the KISS approach; your factory approach seems pure overkill to me.